# ffmpeg: can options -vf and -vcodec and -acodec be used at the same time?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to generate a video file from a number of images. I need to generate wmv files on Mac, so the `-vcodec msmpeg4 -acodec wmav2` options were set.

The video wasn't in the right dimensions, so I added, `-vf scale=512:384`. The colleague who received the file could no longer play the video on Windows using Media Player.

Is there a way to fix this? Could the `-vf` option co-exist with `-vcodec` and `-acodec`?

Comment: You need to show your full command and the complete console output.

Comment: Yes, they can be used together. Something else is the issue here.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard  @Mulvya I am using saveVideo in R. `oopts = ani.options(ffmpeg = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg")`       `saveVideo({ generating graphs }, video.name = FileN, other.opts = "-b:v 2M -vcodec msmpeg4 -acodec wmav2 -vf scale=512:384")`

Comment: You should get the `ffmpeg` command working first, manually in command-line interface, before you attempt to script it. We still need to see the actual, full, unscripted `ffmpeg` command and the complete console output. If that works as expected then we know the issue is likely with your script.